# Perform a query with association aggregates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have 2 models that have an association, say:

```
class Visit
 # column names: made_purchases, purchase_amount
 has_many :payments
end

class Payment
 # column names: amount
 belongs_to :visit
end
```

Now, I want to perform a query for all visits where either of the following matches:

```
1. made_purchases is true
OR
2. purchase_amount is not null
OR
3. has any associated payments
```

I've tried to create a subquery to count the number of payments and tried to use it with my WHERE query, but I can't use aggregate functions on `WHERE`, another option I could use would have been `HAVING` but I'm not sure how that would work in this case

I'm looking for either a query that can easily be done either with ActiveRecord or Arel composition that basically does something like:

## Pseudocode:

```
WHERE visits.made_purchases = true OR visits.purchase_amount is NOT NULL OR HAVING COUNT(*) of payments > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that even though a `HAVING` clause is useful for groups, you can still add the row filters and get the desired results.

Here, I ended up with:

```
Visits.having("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments WHERE payments.visit_id= visits.id)  > 0 OR visits.made_purchases= true OR (visits.purchase_amount IS NOT NULL AND visits.purchase_amount != '')")
```